# Is there a way to make irreflexive property chains in OWL2?

Tags: rdf, owl, ontology, protege

Let's say we have a small ontology about family relations. I'd like to infer indirect relations such as aunt and uncle.

It seems appealing to use property chains for this, but those always end up being reflexive. For instance, if trying to infer sibling like this:

```
:sibling owl:propertyChainAxiom ( :child [owl:inverseOf :child])
```

every person end up being their own sibling. This means that building a chain for uncle/aunt based on sibling relations is impossible.

Any hints how to otherwise achieve this?

Comment: What happens if you state that the property `:sibling` is irreflexive?

Comment: An error in reasoning, because property chains only work with simple classes.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but I had the same problem and used SWRL Rules to fix this.

Example for brother

```
isParentOf(?parent, ?child2) ^ isSonOf(?child, ?parent) ^ DifferentFrom(?child, ?child2) -> isBrotherOf(?child, ?child2)
```